# Firebase check item if exist

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm saving an id to Firebase Realtime Database like this:

```
binding.ivStar.setOnClickListener {
        firebaseDb.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("movie").push()
            .setValue(args.movie?.id)}
```

And I need to check if this id exists in Firebase. And I did like this:

```
private fun checkData() {
    val postRef = firebaseDb.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("movie")

    postRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Log.e("Fragment", "${args.movie?.title} exists")

            } else {
                Log.e("Fragment", "${args.movie?.title} not exists")

            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("Fragment", error.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Every time I check, it returns movie exists even if I don't save it. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> every time I check, it returns a movie exists even if I don't save it.

This is happening because when you attach a listener to the following reference:

```
val postRef = firebaseDb.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("movie")
```

It checks if the `movie` node exists, and not a particular movie. Since under that node, most likely there are multiple movies, `snapshot.exists()` will always return true. If you want to check the existence of a particular movie, you need to add the corresponding ID to the reference:

```
val postRef = firebaseDb.getReference("Users")                   
                        .child(uid)
                        .child("movie")
                        .child("movieIdFromDatabase") //
```

Where `movieIdFromDatabase` should be the ID from the database, the one that starts with `-`.

Comment: Hey there. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: when I saving I used push() code. It returns random key and for its value I set movie's id. So when I search for it it always return negative. Now I changed saving login like this:  firebaseDb.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("movie").child(args.movie?.id.toString()).setValue(args.movie?.id)
and used your code for checking. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try `snapshot.getValue<>()` and then check if this value is null or not maybe that help

Comment: it didn't work.